# Multiple statements in Select Case vba

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to use the Select Case option in excel vba to filter the right data. 
I do the following :

```
For i = 2 To LastRow  

    StartTime = Worksheets("Task input").Cells(1 + i, 9)
    Status = Worksheets("Task input").Cells(1 + i, 14)

    Select Case StartTime And Status

           Case TimeWindowBound1 To TimeWindowBound2 And "Planned"
                Worksheets("Performance output").Cells(5, 2) = Worksheets("Performance output").Cells(5, 2) + 1

    End Select

Next i
```

He compares the StartTime and the Status. However this give an error? Any solution?

Comment: Is this work? I think that It can't work.

Comment: @Nicolas it doesn't work and therefore this question ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that directly in the select case

(documentation of Select case https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx)

The select case can work only on a single variable.
But here the solution is not really complicated:

```
Select Case StartTime
Case TimeWindowBound1 To TimeWindowBound2
    If Status = "Planned" then Worksheets("Performance output").Cells(5, 2) = Worksheets("Performance output").Cells(5, 2) + 1
End Select
```

Comment: Porte, Thank's for your reply! Simple solution indeed ;)

Answer (score 0):

Really, I am surprise with your code. I haven't found anything like this.

You need to know one thing is that `SELECT CASE [condition] AND [condition]` cannot use in any where.

But you need to check both, so try as follow:

```
Public Sub testSelect()

    Dim sDate As Date
    Dim sString As String

    'Set test date
    sDate = "10/02/2014"

    'Set test string
    sString = "select"

    'First select date, because it need to check in a range
    Select Case sDate

        'If it is in desire range, check string
        Case "10/01/2014" To "10/30/2014"

            'If string is equal, show message for True.
            If sString = "select" Then
                MsgBox ("True")

            'Else show message for False
            Else
                MsgBox ("False")
            End If

    End Select

End Sub
```